# equation in function declaration

Tags: c++, function, function-declaration

In C++ (Microsoft Visual Studio), I have: main_savitch_4::string::string(const char str[ ] = "") in mystring.h and added to in mystring.cpp:

```
main_savitch_4::string::string(const char str[ ] = ""){
    allocated = 0;  
    current_length = 0;
    start = new char[0];
}, which defines the private variables.
```

I get the following errors:

```
c:\users\erice\documents\c++_2\lab04\rice_lab04_2\rice_lab04_2\mystring.cpp(13): error C2572: 'main_savitch_4::string::string' : redefinition of default parameter : parameter 1
1>          c:\users\erice\documents\c++_2\lab04\rice_lab04_2\rice_lab04_2\mystring.h(88) : see declaration of 'main_savitch_4::string::string'
1>.
```

What exactly is going wrong???  I don't understand what = means in a function description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you have the default parameter in the declaration and definition of the function. Remove it from the definition:

```
main_savitch_4::string::string(const char str[ ]) { ... }
```

> I don't understand what = means in a function description

It means you are providing a derfault parameter to a function. For example,

```
void foo(int i = 42); // declaration
```

The above means you can call `foo` without a parameter:

```
....
void foo(int i) { return i+100; } // definition

// call the function
foo(); // calls it as foo(42);
foo(123);
```

Comment: When I change it to:main_savitch_4::string::string(char* start = ""){
 allocated = 0;  
 current_length = 1;
 start = new char[1];
}
I get the following error:>c:\users\erice\documents\c++_2\lab04\rice_lab04_2\rice_lab04_2\mystring.cpp(13): error C2572: 'main_savitch_4::string::string' : redefinition of default parameter : parameter 1
1>          c:\users\erice\documents\c++_2\lab04\rice_lab04_2\rice_lab04_2\mystring.h(88) : see declaration of 'main_savitch_4::string::string'
1>
1>Build FAILED.    ANy thoughts?

Comment: @user963070 it is the same error. You are setting a default parameter in the function definition as well as its declaration. Do it only in the declaration.